# Determine if there is a famous person in an array

Tags: algorithm

I'm given an array of n people. And we say that a person is famous if he/she doesn't know anyone from the remaining n-1 people and also, that all n-1 people know that person. Pretty logical. I need to construct an algorithm of complexity $\mathcal{O}(n)$ , but nothing clever crosses my mind. Brute force finishes with $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ and some kind of fast sorting ends up with $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$. Do you guys have any idea on how to approach this problem ?

EDIT: I'm already given a function called know(person a,person b) that determines whether person a knows person b. Also, knowing someone doesn't have to be symmetrical. Otherwise, the problem itself wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @HarshalParekh I tried brute force and list sorting, but that obviously cannot work. I need a new approach. Language-wise, no specific language is needed. Pseudocode is just as fine as python for example.

Comment: @HarshalParekh If those things you mentioned are the reasons why I got two downvotes, then I must say that is pretty unfair. I know how these things works. I couldn't imagine in what way would me telling obvious wrong approaches to this problem help anyone here to provide the better answer for this specific question.

Comment: You may refer to this for better understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @HarshalParekh For example {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}. No details are important at all. The idea is what is the crucial thing here.

Comment: `a person is famous if he/she doesn't know anyone from the remaining n-1 people` from the array example you gave, how is it determined if `h` does not know `a`?

Comment: @HarshalParekh if know(h,a)=0 for example. Or if know(h,a)=false.

Comment: If you can give an example input and output, it will help us understand better. So far, I would say we do not have enough information to help you. Thus, the downvotes.

Comment: You need to mention that in the question. Because that also counts towards the complexity.

Comment: @HarshalParekh I wanted to get 20 rep points so I could join chat rooms so I asked a question here I already know solution for.

Answer (score 0):

We start by asking persons who we don't know anything about, if (a) doesn't know (b), then (b) isn't famous, and  if(a) knows (b), then (a) is not famous. We'll continue this kind of question till there are one person who we don't know anything about (in every question, at least we find out that one new person is not famous, so it's at most n-1 questions)

after that, in 2 * (n-1) questions we check if the suspected famous person is really famous (through checking with everyone else)

so it's of  O(N) complexity over all.

Comment: The OP already knows the solution, I am voting to close this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010714/determine-if-there-is-a-famous-person-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment104270430_59010714